# Could not find implicit value for parameter messages

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, message, playframework-2.4

I'm new to both Scala and Play, so figured I'd start simple with a basic form (following the Play tutorials). I've been trying to solve the following error for 2 days now:

> could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
> formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.contact.index(formWithErrors))

This is the code I have so far:

Controller:

```
package controllers.contact

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.contact.UserData

class ContactController extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.contact.index(UserData.form))
    }

    def create = Action { implicit request =>
        UserData.form.bindFromRequest().fold(
                formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.contact.index(formWithErrors)),
                customer => Ok(s"Customer ${customer.name} created")
            )
    }
}
```

View:

```
@import play.api.data.Form
@import helper._
@import models.contact.UserData
@(form: Form[UserData])(implicit messages: Messages)

@main("") {
    @helper.form(action = controllers.contact.routes.ContactController.create()) {
        @helper.inputText(form("name"))
        @helper.inputText(form("age"))
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    }
}
```

Model:

```
package models.contact

import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

case class UserData(val name: String, val age: Int)

object UserData {
    val form = Form(
            mapping (
                "name" -> text,
                "age" -> number
            )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply)
        )
}
```

Am I missing something painfully obvious? A shove in the right direction would be really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can remove the second parameter list from your Form, as you don't use the parameter `messages` anywhere.  That will solve your compile error.

```
@(form: Form[UserData])(implicit messages: Messages)
```

Can be

```
@(form: Form[UserData])
```

If you *are* planning to use internationalized messages, you should make available an `implicit val messages = ...` in the scope where you call the view.  The normal way of doing this is to put your messages in an external file, `conf/messages` and mix I18nSupport into your controller, which will provide the implicit messages value as [described here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I initially didn't have that declaration in my view (or anywhere else), but I was getting the same error but for the following line `@helper.inputText(form("age"))` (and the one above). Hence adding it in. However, that only seemed to "shift the blame" onto the controller

Comment: You're welcome.  I expanded the answer to give more information about how you can get the `messages` value.  Let me know if that still doesn't fix it.

Comment: Had to do a bit more lifting to get it to work. I needed a parameterless constructor in order for the solution to work at runtime. So I needed to add the `@Inject()` annotation from `javax.inject._`. I'm sure I tried that with no luck previously. Though, considering I'm on here asking, I must've screwed something up on it. Anyway, you gave me a great shove in the right direction so marking this as the answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Your template requires two parameter list

```
@(form: Form[UserData])(implicit messages: Messages)
```

but you are passing only userData (formWithErrors) form

```
formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.contact.index(formWithErrors))
```

You need to either pass Message manualy as

```
formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.contact.index(formWithErrors)(message))
```

or 
declare message as implicit variable in scope as

```
implicit val message: Message = ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I guess I should have been a bit clearer regarding the controller aspect. My issue is how to define a valid `Message` but I'll have a look through the documentation before bothering you further ;) In fact, I should have perhaps done that in the first place....